# How does Jboss Timeout works?

Tags: jboss, timeout, web-applications

How does timeout in jboss works? How does a web-app knows when to re-direct to a login page?

Just to clarify!
-I know how to configure timeout on jboss. My question is, how does Jboss know that a session has timed out and when it does, how do you configure it to send the request to login page once the timeout has happened?

Comment: session-timeout property. How does jboss decides where to throw you out; when your session has expired.

Comment: what kinda timout do you have?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure a time out on an all deployable units like .war files in web.xml

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpSession` timeout in JBoss can be set at three different levels:

- ***#1*** To change default timeout value for every web application:

Edit the Web Deployer's default wed application configuration: in the `web.xml`

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

- ***#2*** To override the default `HttpSession` timeout on a per-webapp basis:

Add the same tags as above to `WEB-INF/web.xml`.  Here is the DTD for further explanation:

```
<!--
The session-config element defines the session parameters for
this web application.

Used in: web-app
-->
<!ELEMENT session-config (session-timeout?)>
```

From https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HttpSessionTimeout

> The session-timeout element defines the default session timeout
>   interval for all sessions created in this web application. The
>   specified timeout must be expressed in a whole number of minutes.
>   If the timeout is 0 or less, the container ensures the default
>   behaviour of sessions is never to time out.
>   Used in: session-config
>
> `<!ELEMENT session-timeout (#PCDATA)>`

- ***#3***  To override the global and web app value for a single client,

call

```
HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int seconds)
```